# Does Express access an app.get(/:params) if the user didn't type anything in the URL

Tags: node.js, express

My code goes like this:

```
    app.get("/:pageName",function(req,res){
  const listName=req.params.pageName;
  console.log(listName)
  const list = new List({name:listName,items:defaultItems});
  list.save();
});
```

If I only typed in the URL bar in the browser "http://localhost:3000/" does the app execute the previous code or not?

If it does, how can I tell it not to?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: of course i tried it , it is executing the code inside without me typing anything after the "http://localhost:3000/" i will edit my full code in the question  . also i read the docs they didnt mention anything regarding my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no - express will only resolve a non-empty value as a path parameter, unless you use some wildcard (e.g, `?`) to make it optional.